# Is there any way to get notified when user dial any number on phone dialpad?

Tags: android

I want to know if there is any possibility to get notified using Broadcast Receivers when user enters any number in dial pad. I want to get notified when user enters the number in dial pad like 531 etc.

Comment: I am not sure that there is any intent being sent when this happens, however maybe there is an intent when user calls this number

Comment: Yes, broadcast action for call is available, but I am looking for dial pad. Even if a single digit is pressed.

Comment: Have you seen some app doing this? It seems like a logic, that breaks security.